# Why do I get a "client network socket disconnected before secure tls connection was established" error?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send emails. When sending emails on AWS lambda I get

`client network socket disconnected before secure tls connection was established`

It is working on my local machine and also working lamda on test environment but not production lambda. Also, this error occurs only one of our clients.

I have researched the error. Some others encountered this error on AWS lambda and they advised that wait until promise completed but we already waiting for promises to complete. And I couldn't find any other solution.

What could be the problem and how can I solve it.